# How to use webmethod to send two variables from server to client side during multiple button loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

Let's say I have a Button1 containing other three buttons:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button2_Click(this, null);
    Button3_Click(this, null);
    Button4_Click(this, null);
}
```

Button2 contains two integers:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = 10;
    int x2 = 5;
}
```

When I click Button1 it calls all these other buttons. When Button1 fires, first loads Button2 and I want these two variable values to send to client side JavaScript to take it before Button3 loads:

```
function TakeVariables()
{ 
    var x_javaS = document.getElementById('<%=x%>').value;
    var x2_javaS = document.getElementById('<%=x2%>').value;
}
```

Is there any solution with webmethod or pagemethod to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in one round trip. When button 1 is clicked, then WHOLE page is now up on the server. At that point, calling 2 or 10 other code stubs (be they other button stubs, or just code routines) does not matter.

During that time the page is up on the server, you can't send anything back to the client UNLESS you let the whole page lifecycle complete.

And you "never" send values from the server, the server "responds" to requests from the client side. So that "concept" of returning values? No, you return a web page AFTER the page lifecycle completes.

Once that page is "up on" the server, then code behind can ONLY modify the "dom" of the browser page. To send anything back to the client, you can even use multiple "response" methods, but they are all built up, and they ALL come back as a whole page load WHEN your code 100% completes.

As I noted and pointed out in my last "long" response?

You could use say 5 buttons on the page, and click button 1, post-back, and after/when the page lifecycle completes, you could click on button 2 (with a injected javascript code stub as I did). In that example, I wind up clicking the ONE button 5 times - once for each step.

However, that example was a "proof" of concept based on "using" our new found knowledge of the page life cycle.

and I stated that using a update panel, and having the one button be clicked again and again was "somewhat" better then dropping in 5 buttons to do the same thing.

However, if you note close, I ALSO suggested/hinted/stated/implied that to do this type of updating of the web page, we are MUCH better to go down the road of using a web method. That means AJAX calls, and that means we do NOT use a page post-back.

So the "whole" idea of adopting AJAX calls is that we don't use nor have (or some would say "suffer" a post-back, and thus we are NOT dealing with a page round trip).

In fact, most of the new web technologies seek to provide users with a desktop like experience, and that means developers work hard to reduce those so called "round trips". thus, you can update parts of the screen, and do so without a browser re-load and round trip. The "more" code, and the "more" things you can have occur in the browser without a round trip? Then the more of a desktop like experience we can provide for the end user.

In effect, what is occuring is devleopers are moving more and more server code to the client side!!! But, then again, that often becomes more work.

So, for most basic pages, we do allow and have round trips. This makes web develpment super easy. (and is one big reason why so many love web-forms). However, the "down side" is that you suffer a lot of "round trips".

So, to make a long story short?

In that previous example, I on "purpose" used as little or no JavaScript, and wanted a pure webforms example of how to update the "progress" of each routine we wanted to run.

However, I ALSO stated that with a bit more efforts, I perfer and think the AJAX road is a better road. the ONLY trick then is to seutp some code that does not break the bank coding wise.

In other words, say we want to call 5 buttons, but we remove the buttons, and create 5 code routines (code behind). If we tag those 5 routines as web methods, then we can run a loop client side in js, and call all 5 of them, and EVERN better is the code flow is quite easy.

We setup progress bar, maybe show message, and THEN call the one server side method. but we not using a button click anymore - but a ajax call, and thus no round trip. When the code is done, then js can "move on" to step 2.

Since no post-backs are occurring, then this works well. The only trick is I don't want to create 5 local JavaScript routines to do this, (or maybe 8 routines).

so, I now tend to use this design pattern, and it works rather well:

First up, our button click now DOES NOT have a server side code event stub. We not going to do a post-back (no round trip) with this button.

So, this design I find works rather well:

So say in code behind we have 5 steps. We tag the code behind as web methods.

So, say like this:

```
    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Step1()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "done";
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Step2()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "done";
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Step3()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "done";
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Step4()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "done";
    }

    [WebMethod()]
    public static string Step5()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "done";
    }
```

Now of course in above, I "fake" a 2 second processing delay.

So, now, let's use "ajax", and not use post-backs to call the above 5 steps.

And note that EACH step in theory can return more then one value. I return "done", but you CAN return multiple values!

So, in effect, for each step, between a step, you can return MORE then one value from the server.

And now our client side code looks like this:

```
        function runajax() {
            mybar2()

            runFunctions =
                [
                { Method: "Step1", MyMessage: "Computer Starting" },
                { Method: "Step2", MyMessage: "Start Fuel Flow" },
                { Method: "Step3", MyMessage: "Wait for Turbine" },
                { Method: "Step4", MyMessage: "Engine at speed - generating power" },
                { Method: "", MyMessage: "Done - final message" }
                ]

            runPtr = 0
            runsteps()
        }


        function runsteps() {

            // update text box, show step
            $('#pmsgdiv').text(runFunctions[runPtr].MyMessage)

            var funcstep = runFunctions[runPtr].Method
            mybar2(runPtr + 1)
            if (funcstep == "") {
                // this is to ignore a blank fucntion - allows final step message
                return
            }
            var myurl = "StepProcess.aspx/" + funcstep

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: myurl,
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (rData) {
                    // step done, move on to next one
                    runPtr++
                    if (runPtr < runFunctions.length) {
                        runsteps()
                    }
                },
                failure: function (rData) {
                    alert("error " + rData.d);
                }
            });
        }
```

So, now we are NOT using the page life cycle. You find the above runs "butter" smooth, and no page post-back occurs.

this:

[image]

And yes, you can return multiple values using the above approach for each step.

So, I'll try a post some more code examples here.

So, I used the above approach for this example:

[image]

So, the web method looks like this:

(this example is vb.net, but it don't matter)

```
<WebMethod>
Public Shared Function GetUpLoads() As Dictionary(Of String, String)
```

so, I return a dictionary of values to the ajax call

the final steps look like this:

```
    Dim mValues As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    mValues.Add("TotalFiles", TotalFiles)
    mValues.Add("PdfFiles", PdfFiles)
    mValues.Add("ZipFiles", ZipFiles)
    mValues.Add("FilesPerDay", FilesPerDay)

    Return mValues

End Function
```

So, I am returning 4 values to the ajax call.

The ajax call thus can do this on return:

```
    function gFiles(Data) {
        // file uploaded info
        gaugeFilesUpLoaded.refresh(Data.TotalFiles, Data.TotalFiles, 0)
        gaugePdfFiles.refresh(Data.PdfFiles,Data.TotalFiles, 0)
        gaugeZipFiles.refresh(Data.ZipFiles,Data.TotalFiles, 0)
        gaugeFilesPerDay.refresh(Data.FilesPerDay,10,0)
    }
```

So, note how I returned 4 values from the ajax  call.

So, you don't have the server "send" multiple values, but you sure can have the ajax call "request" values from a web method, and you not limited to one return value.

So, all in all?

For these types of "progress" updates? Then ajax in near all cases is a better approach then having say a post-back (round trip), and then on each return of the round trip, we use js code to "click" a button to continue the progress.

And note that you can now even adopt a "polling" approach. You could have a long running server bit of code, and say every 1 second use ajax calls to get/grab the current progress amount (say at 1 second intervals). This is possible since you not using round trips and post-backs anymore.